# Alternative layperson-friendly names for 'Legend'?

Tags: web-mapping, cartography, legend, ux

I am making a mobile mapping app that has a button that displays a legend. Because my legend is initially hidden from view, it is really important the text I put in the button that displays the legend, be understandable to the decent amount of people who dont know what the word "Legend" refers to on its own.

Since it is a mobile app, I only have so much space available, so shorter suggestions (approx. 10 characters) are ideal.

All the alternatives I can think of are equally ambiguous:

```
-Icon Key
-Marker Key (my data is all points)
-Map key
-Info/ the 'i' info symbol 
-the icon seen on many mobile apps, three parallel horizontal bars
```

Ideas?

Comment: "Map Key" fits your criteria and is the most common name for a Legend. Your website http://kidfriendlyplaces.org/ is very informative and easy to use, good work.

Comment: How about "Map Symbols", "Symbols", "Key", "Map Help"?  Or ["Secret Decoder Ring"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secret_decoder_ring)... everyone knows that from the backs of cereal boxes :)

Comment: Map Key would be generic and if in the future contained 'lines' (i.e. kid friendly bike trails for example) then no changes would be required.

Comment: how about "index", not great but 5 letters :)

Comment: What about a question mark?

Answer (score 2):

I would leave it as Legend.

Maps have been around for a long time and although legend may not be universally understood I think any alternatives (except possibly Key) will be far less so.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen the word "references" used. In spanish, "referencia" is standard.

Answer (score 1):

I've used "Explanation" a lot in the past on maps - you are explaining what the symbols mean. This may be a couple too many characters for your needs, however.

Comment: Hrm. Im probably not going to use this for my app, but I can see myself using that for other mapping purposes!