# What would be a good symbol for the map legend itself?

Tags: web-mapping, legend, design

I am reformatting a mobile web map. Many of our users are equipped with mobile phones rather than large tablets, so screen real estate is at a premium. I've decided to remove the legend from default view for these devices. Users will have to click on or hover over a small control button to view the legend.

So naturally, I now need a symbol that conveys "legend" to place on the control button. Leading candidates:

- A key: intuitive, but it says "key" more than "legend". A difference many users might not care about, but I do...
- A question mark: it's engaging and implies it can answer questions about the map.
- <del>Will Smith</del>
- The word "legend". This is a last resort. The other control buttons have icons, so this would kind of throw a wrench in the works, but it definitely conveys the concept of a legend.

I'm not completely satisfied with any of these, which is why I've come to you. What says legend without saying legend?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

not sure if the users are IOS or Android but maybe the list/interface icon it would go nicely with what the user is used to seeing in other apps, unless of course its already being used for something else.

[image]

Comment: I received that suggestion from a coworker, but I felt this symbol has strong connotations with "menu". While menus are certainly meta to the map like legends, they are links to multiple meta items, whereas a legend is a single meta item.

Comment: Okay, you've won me over. My previous concerns have been assuaged by realizing that this actually is pretty standard. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I'd say it should look something like this: https://www.iconfinder.com/icons/64438/legend_icon#size=32

[image]

Comment: Could you attach this image within your answer, link only answers may lead to a disconnect in the future.

Comment: This is similar to Chris R's response, except the coloring helps drive the concept of "legend" home. Most of the control icons we have are monochrome, but I might find a way to integrate something similar to this.

Answer (score 0):

I like the stacked paper look.  The image helps the user know there are layer options available.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, we're not trying to denote layers, just a legend. Plus, we're already using stacked papers for our base layers menu control icon: http://leafletjs.com/examples/layers-control.html

Answer (score 0):

I would go with a logo of a legendary *figure* , instead of a abstract symbol for legend. Notice that the almost-universal, though outdated figure for "Save" is not a representation of saving something (like a hand putting something into a bag or something), but something that saves: a floppy diskette.

So, what's a concrete example for a figure that's legendary? I would say rock god David St. Hubbins of Spinal Tap. Just a little gif of his face should be sufficient to show a representation of something that's le - gen - waitforit - dary.

Comment: You get some lols, though for the record, I sorta made that joke in my question with the Will Smith strikethrough ("I Am Legend reference).

Answer (score 0):

I asked a similar question a while ago. You can find the responses [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/71003/alternative-layperson-friendly-names-for-legend).

My app already uses the list interface icon for a drop down menu, so for the legend I opted for a button with text "filter places" which isnt perfect, but I cant think of anything better (In my legend you can turn layers on and off). Very small screens see a filter icon instead of button text.